Python Flask Ubuntu Apache2 website, serving images outside of DocumentRoot using apache2's alias_mod. Am I missing something?
Context:
I created a webtool using Python Flask to retrieve filenames from a database with a backend sql post method to my database code. This works fine. Filenames are always returned appropriately and presented to the client with file sizes. The client then selects which files they wish to download and hits go. They will receive a link via email to download the files in a zip (downloads are usually very large, the client request prompts the files to be prepared in a zip, which is then made into a link and emailed to the client).
Next functionality and explored solutions:
One query the filenames returned reference .png files and I would like to have them as clickable links where the user could click them and see the actual png file (rather than have to go through the email route). The data exists on the server outside of the webtools DocumentRoot. Moving the data inside of this projects DocumentRoot would be inappropriate as many other webtools use the data. Duplicating the data is infeasible as we're talking >100TB. One solution I found to access data outside of documentRoot is apache2's mod_alias. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html
I set up the mod alias in apache2/mods-available/alias.conf
Alias "/pngs/" "/home/myuser/data/pngs/"
<Directory "/home/myuser/data/pngs/">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I then reference the png file in my html code with an <a href="/pngs/file1.png"> file 1 </a>
Clicking the link takes me to https://myurl.com/pngs/file1.png but I get a 404. Am I missing something?

Make sure the Apache user has filesystem permissions on those directories (and parent directories).

This could just be it. I don't think the user of the data directory is www-data:www-data. I'll try this and hopefully it doesn't break other processing code! Like in my project there's the app/static directory... I should be able to see the directory structure if I just go to https://myurl.com/app/static/ right? So if I go to https://myurl.com/pngs/ I should see the data directory structure... Though I do still get a 404 if I try to go to app/static... I thought I'd be able to see the directory.

There's a separate setting to enable browsing directory indices in Apache. By default, directory browsing is disabled, IIRC. You could probably also add a specific rule for when a user requests a directory (and not a file) if you want Apache to do something else instead of giving a 404.

Was hoping you'd reply with that exact information. Thank you very much! Will try setting the permissions tomorrow.
